# Including Image in Velocity Template using Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail, velocity

Trying to set an image as logo. Html is placed in velocity template.

```
 ApplicationContext appContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext();
 Resource resource = appContext.getResource( "file:/D:/img/x.png" );
 MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
 MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper( message,
                                                     true,
                                                     "UTF-8" );
 helper.addInline( "imageContent",
                    new File( resource.getURI() ));
 //code to send the message

 In .vm file,
      <img src=\"cid:imageContent\"/>
```

The image is not being rendered in the e-mail. What am I doing wrong here?
If I send the image as an attachment, it is being rendered properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this resolved. `<img src='cid:imageContent'/>` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add any absolute path for image of your system, instead you should put your image in some CDN and include the URL for the same in your template. Then only it will be rendered in your email.

Comment: But addInline() takes a file and a resource, so why wouldn't it work with absolute path?  If my webapp is running and I give a relative path to pick the image from classpath, would that suffice?